# How to convert mnist dataset in array

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

Hello consider following code

```
# load the mnist training data CSV file into a list
training_data_file = open("Training_Set/mnist_train_100.csv", 'r')
training_data_list = training_data_file.readlines()
training_data_file.close()


for record in training_data_list:
    all_values = record.split(',')
    x_inputs = (np.asfarray(all_values[1:]) / 255.0 * 0.99) + 0.01

print("xinput=" + str(x_inputs))
print(len(training_data_list))
MyCompleteInput = np.array(x_inputs,len(training_data_list))
```

I want to put x_inputs and len(training_data_list) into an array so if I print the shape of the array I get an output of (784,100).

But if I run my code I get following error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-38-b0f129f57bcb> in <module>()
     11 print("xinput=" + str(x_inputs))
     12 print(len(training_data_list))
---> 13 MyCompleteInput = np.array(x_inputs,len(training_data_list))
     14 
     15 

TypeError: data type not understood
```

Can somebody help me out? tnx

Answer (score 0):

The line will be

MyCompleteInput = np.array((x_inputs,len(training_data_list)))

Do this and your error will be gone. You need to add another set of parantheses for specifying the size.

Comment: Thank you, but I wondering now. As you know my dataset.csv contains 100 records and each record exists of 1 label (y) and 784 pix (x). I exclude the y in all_values. MyCompleteInput, will it really have as content now the 100 records and 784 pix or is it just an array with size (784,100)? The goal is to have an array of shape (784,100) but also at the same time that does contain the content of my csv file. Did I archive that by above code?

Comment: No it won't have the values received from the MNIST csv file. This will just instantiate an array of the given size. So, what you could do is to first instantiate this array and then copy the valus from the csv file into that specified array. MyCompleteInput[:,i] = (np.asfarray(all_values[1:]) / 255.0 * 0.99) + 0.01